# Ansible: Multiple and/or conditionals in when clause

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am having issues when trying to use multiple and/or conditionals in a when statement to decide whether a task needs to be ran or not. Basically I am making a playbook to do automated system patching with options for security patches, kernel only patches and to specify packages in a var file.

I run the playbook with the following commands and define the variables through extended variables option (-e)

```bash
ansible-playbook site.yml \
  -i inventory \
  --ask-vault \
  -u (username) \
  -e "security=true restart=true" \
  -k -K
```

By default the playbook will update every package on the system except kernel but I would like to skip that action if I specify any of a few variables. The code I have is the following:

```yaml
- name: Update all packages
  yum:
    name: "*"
    state: latest
    exclude: "kernel*"
  when: >
    security is not defined or
    kernel is not defined or
    specified_packages is not defined
    and ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
```

I've tried all of the following combinations:

```yaml
when: (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") and (security is defined or kernel is defined or specified_packages is defined)

# this case throws a not defined error because i don't define all variables every time i run the playbook
when: (ansible_os_family == "RedHat") and (security == true or kernel == true or specified_packages == true )

when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
when: security is defined or kernel is defined or specified_packages is defined
```

**Note:** I am aware and have used an extra variable such as "skip" to skip this task and use the when clause `when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and skip is not defined` but would prefer not have my users need to use an extra variable just to skip this default action.

I also am not using tags as I am gathering a list of packages before and after the upgrade to compare and report in the end so I wont be able to run those as they are local action commands. This is why I'm using one role with multiple tasks turned on and off via extended variables. I am open to any suggestion that rewrites the playbook in a more efficient way as I am sort of a noob.

Comment: Yes, you can't combine `is defined` with other conditions this way. It won't work if a variable is undefined.

Comment: So there is no way to run a task based on whether a list of variables are defined or not along with a check for OS? It works for one like this `when: ansible_os_family and security is not defined` but not multiple...

Comment: Yes, there can be only one `is defined` and, if I remember correctly it should be at the end. The problem is that Ansible internally always faces an exception when a variable is not defined. Then it looks for `defined` condition and if it's there, it handles the exception instead of failing. But it cannot handle multiple conditions. You'd need to refactor the code either to contain `default` filter or additional facts only for the purpose of checking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It was such a simple answer!

The following works:

```yaml
when: not (security is defined or kernel is defined or specified_packages is defined) and ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
```

Answer (score 9):

As @techraf noted in comments, `defined`/`undefined` is a nasty test...

Refactor like this:

```yaml
when:
  - ansible_os_family == "RedHat"
  - security|d('') != '' or kernel|d('') != '' or specified_packages|d('') != ''
```

Update. Reproducible example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - debug:
      msg: hello
      when:
        - '"RedHat" == "RedHat"'
        - security|d('') != '' or kernel|d('') != '' or specified_packages|d('') != ''
```

execution:

```
ansible-playbook -e kernel=true playbook.yml

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "hello"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

versions:

```
$ pip list | grep -iP 'ansible|jinja'
ansible (2.2.1.0)
Jinja2 (2.8)
```

Comment: Unfortunately It only works for one..If I specify the first variable it works fine but if i specify the second variable it throws the error:`"the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'kernel' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in`

Comment: What versions of Ansible and Jinja2 do you use? This expression works just fine with recent versions: it will run the task if os is RedHat AND any of security/kernel/specified_packages is set.

Comment: Not sure how to check the Jinja version but was on ansible 2.2.0 just updates to 2.3.1 to see if that works but no luck. The conditional check for os AND the first defined variable combination works but if i define a variable thats not in the first slot it throws an error about the first variable not being defined. e.g if I say  kernel = true it says security is not defined

Comment: Also what does |d do in Jinja..cant seem to find it online?

Comment: Added reproducible example. `d` is alias for [default](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#default)

Comment: Ah seems to be a little bit of confusion I want the task to skip if kernel/security/specified_packages is set to true (defined). I've tried to make != to == but that doesnt work.. Im a noob. Also my versions are: `ansible (2.3.1.0)
Jinja2 (2.7.2)
`

Comment: It looks like the jinja |d doesnt work as the value is true before and after but the conditions still run..`TASK [common : debug] 
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "true"
}

TASK [common : debug] 
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "hello"
}

TASK [common : debug] 
ok: [host] => {
    "msg": "true"
}
`

Answer (score 3):

I just had a similar problem needing to test two different variables to see if they were "true", but they don't always exist in the output json.  The basic logic needed is:

```
( a is defined ) and ( a == 'present' or a == 'reinstalled' )
```

in this case, a is "install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state", and the following three different scenarios produced the correct result:

direct:

```
when: (install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state is defined) and (install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state == 'reinstalled' or install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state == 'present')
```

distributed:

```
when: (install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state is defined and install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state == 'present') or (install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state is defined and install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state == 'reinstalled')
```

broken into lines that imply 'and' or 'intersection', except it stops if the first item evaluates to false.

```
when:
  - install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state is defined
  - install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state == 'reinstalled' or install_vs2022_status.invocation.module_args.state == 'present'
```

The most important factor in each case is that the test for existence happens first, in order to prevent evaluation of a variable that doesn't exist.

EDIT:  Just learned how to use multi-line 'or' conditionals:

```
- name: get process list
  shell: ps -ef
  when: >
    ("passed" in env_status.stdout) or
    ("fixed" in env.status.stdout)
```

This makes it much more readable when i'm looking for multiple 'or', and parens can be used for multiple combinations of and/or.